# Django how to pass choices list to a custom select widget

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-widget

I need to override select widget.

```
class TooltipSelectWidget(Select) :

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) :
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then I call it in a form. But I do not see in the docs how to pass the choices list to this customed widget.

Answer (score 1):

in your code, after call the super class initializer, set the choices as below:

```
class TooltipSelectWidget(Select) :

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) :
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.choices = []  # List of 2-tuple values
```

If you look at the code of the `__init__` of the `Select` class (Base class for your custom widget) you can get intuition about why this is the solution:

```
class Select(Widget):
    allow_multiple_selected = False

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, choices=()):
        super(Select, self).__init__(attrs)
        # choices can be any iterable, but we may need to render this widget
        # multiple times. Thus, collapse it into a list so it can be consumed
        # more than once.
        self.choices = list(choices)
```

**A better approach** is to have your custom choices by default in your

```
class TooltipSelectWidget(Select) :

   CUSTOM_CHOICES = ()  # Modify at will. 

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, choices=CUSTOM_CHOICES) :
        super().__init__(attrs=attrs, choices=choices)
```

Comment: Based on your great solution, I advise everyone to see [django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L279) for widgets. This completes your explication.

Answer (score 0):

If choix contains the list of tuples for choices, then the code below does the job:

```
form.fields[name] = ChoiceField (widget = TooltipSelectWidget (attrs = attrs, choices = choix) choices = choix)
```

The trick is that the choices list need to be repeated, once for the widget and once for the choicefield)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to form init:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    CHOICES = [()]
    self.fields['choice_field'].choices = CHOICES
```